# How to switch between speaker and headphones in iPhone application

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer, playback

I've written an app that plays audio using AVAudioPlayer.

I've implemented a function that switches the audio to the speaker:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);    
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

But when I try to switch it back to the Headphones using this:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);    
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

it remains routed through the speaker.

I cannot find any other way of directing the audio. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html), the Audio Session route override is only availble when using the `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` category.

You can try changing the category to `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` and use the `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker` property key to route audio to the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Like Laurent said, try using PlayAndRecord like so:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
```

It's very important to use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` or the route will fail to go to the speaker. Once you've set the override route for the audio session, you can use an `AVAudioPlayer` instance and send some output to the speaker.

Hope that works for others like it did for me. The documentation on this is scattered, but the Skype app proves it's possible. Persevere, my friends! :)

Some Apple documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

Do a search on the page for `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute`